# Remove sub-string from python string after comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python string like this;

```
input_str = "2548,0.8987,0.8987,0.1548"
```

I want to remove the sub-string at the end after the last comma, including the comma itself.

The output string should look like this;

```
output_str = "2548,0.8987,0.8987"
```

I am using python v3.6

Comment: What if there was no comma and only one item... would you keep that or not?

Comment: @Jon Clements, The string I have in mind will always have more than 1 item.

Comment: Famous last words :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## With `split` and `join`

```
','.join(input_str.split(',')[:-1])
```

#### Explanation

```
# Split string by the commas
>>> input_str.split(',')
['2548', '0.8987', '0.8987', '0.1548']

# Take all but last part
>>> input_str.split(',')[:-1]
['2548', '0.8987', '0.8987']

# Join the parts with commas
>>> ','.join(input_str.split(',')[:-1])
'2548,0.8987,0.8987'
```

---

## With `rsplit`

```
input_str.rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)[0]
```

---

## With `re`

```
re.sub(r',[^,]*$', '', input_str)
```

If you are gonna to use it multiple times make sure to compile the regex:

```
LAST_ELEMENT_REGEX = re.compile(r',[^,]*$')
LAST_ELEMENT_REGEX.sub('', input_str)
```

Comment: Brilliant. I tested that it works! Now, I am trying to decode what your one-liner does. Seems like there's quite a few operations in that single line.

Comment: Check the other ways, the `rsplit` is the cleanest in my opinion.

Comment: @PacoH. use `.rpartition` - it's optimised for a split case of 0 or 1...

Comment: @Paco H, rsplit is the simplest solution. I can understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's [the split function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) for python :

```
print input_str.split(',')
```

Will return :

```
['2548,0.8987,0.8987', '0.1548']
```

But in case you have multiple commas, [rsplit is here for that](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) :

```
str = '123,456,789'
print str.rsplit(',', 1)
```

Will return :

```
['123,456','789']
```

Comment: No, it won't return that. `split(',')` will split on _every_ comma, not just the last one.

Comment: In this case there's [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit), I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simplest one. Here we are using `split`, `pop` and `join` to achieve desired result.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/870194)

```
input_str = "2548,0.8987,0.8987,0.1548"
list= input_str.split(",") #Split string over ,
list.pop() #pop last element
print(",".join(list)) #joining list again over ,
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is definitely a comma in your string:

```
output_str = input_str[:input_str.rindex(',')]
```

That is "Take everything from the start of the string up to the last index of a comma".

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
sep = ','
count = input_str.count(sep)
int i=0;
output = ''
while(i<count):
    output += input_str.split(sep, 1)[i]
    i++
input_str = output
```